# Unable to set Image src in html using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm new on nodeJS, I'm unable to set src of img tag in my client side html.
as my node server is running on port 3000. which is working fine when I hit http://localhost:3000,

below is code of my **server.js** file

```
var app = require('express')();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/var/www/UI-Test/client.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user joined ');

});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Also code of **client.html** is given below

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="f1.png" /> <!-- also tried "./f1.png" -->

<script>
var socket = io();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It give 404 (Not Found) error even f1.png file is in the same folder as server.js and client.html. My OS is ubuntu by the way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should tell express where is the public assets folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// At the top of your server.js
process.env.PWD = process.cwd()

// Then
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
```

and store your image in `/public/f1.png`
in the html part call

```
<img src="/f1.png" />
```

Comment: app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
        ^
ReferenceError: express is not defined

Comment: var express= require('express');
var app = express();